# ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) interpreting cloudbuild.yaml as build config: .args: unused

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, cloud, node-red

This is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
args: ['build', '-t','us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}','.']
images: 
- 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}'
```

and when i try to run this command

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions=_REPOSITORY="my-repo",_IMAGE="my-node-red"
```

i get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) interpreting cloudbuild.yaml as build config: .args: unused
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to a wrong identation in your `cloudbuild.yaml` file. The correct identation is (mind the 2 spaces before `args`):

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t','us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}','.']
images: 
- 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}'
```

You can then submit the build successfully with the same command you mentioned:

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions=_REPOSITORY="my-repo",_IMAGE="my-node-red"
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Is there a reason to use underscores?